# query notification

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-notifications

could someone pls tell me the version requirements for query notification?
we are running sql server 2008 and use ODBC 3.0 but are still on visual studio 6.
on compile some of the ODBC parameter (ex: SQL_SOPT_SS_QUERYNOTIFICATION_OPTIONS) are not 
found.
any help would be greatly appreciated.
thanks in advance,
Bill Riggio

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to upgrade to the SQL Server Native Client driver (download [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6C3E9EF-BA29-4A43-8D69-A2BED18FE73C&displaylang=en)) to take advantage of query notification. Per Microsoft documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx):

> The SQL Server Native Client ODBC
>   driver supports query notifications
>   through the addition of three new
>   attributes to the SQLGetStmtAttr and
>   SQLSetStmtAttr functions:
>
> SQL_SOPT_SS_QUERYNOTIFICATION_MSGTEXT
>   SQL_SOPT_SS_QUERYNOTIFICATION_OPTIONS
>   SQL_SOPT_SS_QUERYNOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT